# i want to sort my array

Tags: php, sorting

I want to sort my array into newarray. how can i delete the array entry with the first min number?

```
<?php
$array = array(8, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7);
$newarray = array();
$array_size = count ($array);


for ($i = 0; $i<$array_size; $i++) {

        $smallestNumber = min($array);
        $array2[] = $smallestNumber;
        unset($array[$smallestNumber]);
}

print_r($array2);
?>
```

Comment: try this  http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: i want to learn it by hand :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCzQvQr8Utw

Comment: "i want to learn it by hand" usort()

Answer (score 2):

If you are learning programming, then probably you are after some sorting algorithms.
Some good starting points are

1. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm
2. [http://www.amazon.com/Web-Based-Introduction-Programming-Algorithms-Structures/dp/159460844X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/159460844X)
3. https://phpcoderblog.wordpress.com/2013/02/26/php-some-sorting-algorithms-bubble-sort-selection-sort-counting-sort-quicksort-shellsort-heapsort/
4. http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/array-sorting-algorithms-php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is suboptimal (as it iterates through the array multiple times - once for finding the minimal value and once for finding its index), but here is what you could do with the code you have originally posted in order to make it work:

```
<?php
$array = array(8, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 7);
$newarray = array();
$array_size = count ($array);


for ($i = 0; $i<$array_size; $i++) {

        $smallestNumber = min($array);
        $smallestIndex = array_search($smallestNumber, $array)
        $newarray[] = $smallestNumber;
        unset($array[$smallestIndex]);
}

print_r($newarray);
?>
```